# JS functions returning self/object, not running

Tags: javascript

Edit: This code should by all means be working. However it's not working in my app.

So I have a stupid simple view. That has a link which I'm going to use to flush out an Ajax feature. However the JS is not running, it "runs" but each function seems to return itself, and never actually runs. No errors or anything just acting weird. I used thoughtbot suspenders for the app.

```html
// view: app/views/savings/new.html.erb
<h3> <%= title %></h3>

<div>
  <h4 id="suggested-savings-list"> foo
  </h4>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="" class="suggested-savings-btn">Random</a>
</div>
```

```js
// js: app/assets/javascripts/savings/suggested_savings.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $suggestedSavingsBtn = $(".suggested-savings-btn");

  var updateSuggestedSavingsList = function(){
    // var $suggestedSavingsList = $(".suggested-savings-list")
    console.log("clicked")
  };

  $suggestedSavingsBtn.on("click", updateSuggestedSavingsList);
  // $suggestedSavingsBtn.on("click", function(){
  //   var foo = 2;
  //   console.log(foo)
  // });
});
```

If I debug it in console, and call it works, however when run on() is not calling updateSuggestedSavingsList.

```
>updateSuggestedSavingsList() =>
> "clicked"
```

If I step through it, at `on()` it jumps to the closing `})`;

Comment: because `updateSuggestedSavingsList` is a function. If you want to `"clicked"` to appear, you should call it: `updateSuggestedSavingsList()`.

Comment: I do not see any error in my jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: your snippet is actually working on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfLt7/81/)

Comment: Ah yea true in the console I would have to add () to the function call, however that does not explain why on() is not calling the function: updateSuggestedSavingsList()

Comment: @ChrisCPO it does. when you click on the link, if you look at your console, you'll see "clicked" will be printed out. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfLt7/81/)

Comment: `$(".suggested-savings-list")` should be `$("#suggested-savings-list")`. dot is for class, hash is for ID.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually binding that function to that link's `click` event.

this

```
$suggestedSavingsBtn.on("click", updateSuggestedSavingsList);
```

means that "When I clicked on that element, run this function `updateSuggestedSavingsList`".

It just registers the function to the event, if the "click" event on the elemen fires, then the function would be called.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfLt7/81/).

Comment: yea right but when I click on the element it does not get called?

Comment: @ChrisCPO It does, just check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfLt7/81/). Open your console and click on that link ("Random"). You'll see in the console "clicked" would be printed out.

Comment: @ChrisCPO Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Amir I know it works in fiddle, but it's not working in my app, it should but its just not. hence the issue.

Comment: No errors. I used tbot suspenders for the rails. Other then that it's pretty standard.

Comment: @ChrisCPO Well, as far as I can tell, this is a problem with the rest of your project.

Comment: Yea. Perhaps will have to report the issue to the suspenders gem. Thanks for your help.